# Caused by io.lettuce.core.rediscommandexecutionexception: moved 15596 XX.X.XXX.XX:6379 Java Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, lettuce

We have a spring-boot application which is deployed to lambda in AWS.
Code

```
public AbstractRedisClient getClient(String host, String port) {
        LOG.info("redis-uri" + "redis://"+host+":"+port);
        return RedisClient.create("redis://"+host+":"+port);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Redis connection using the Lettuce-Redis-Client
     *
     * @return RedisClient
     */
    public RedisClient getConnection(String host, String port) {
        LOG.info("redis-Host " + host);
        LOG.info("redis-Port " + port);
        RedisClient redisClient = (RedisClient) getClient(host, port);
        redisClient.setDefaultTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        return redisClient;
    }


 private RedisCommands<String, String> getRedisCommands() {
        StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> statefulConnection = openConnection();
        if(statefulConnection != null)
          return statefulConnection.sync();
        else
          return null;
      }
    
      public StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> openConnection() {
    
        if(connection != null && connection.isOpen()) {
          return connection;
        }
        
        String redisPort = "6379";
        String redisHost = environment.getProperty("REDIS_HOST");
        //String redisPort = environment.getProperty("REDIS_PORT");
        LOG.info("Host: {}", redisHost);
        LOG.info("Port: {}", redisPort);
        UnifiedReservationRedisConfig lettuceRedisConfig = new UnifiedReservationRedisConfig();
        String redisUri = "redis://"+redisHost+":"+redisPort;
        redisClient = lettuceRedisConfig.getConnection(redisHost, redisPort);
    
        ConnectionFuture<StatefulRedisConnection<String, String>> future = redisClient
            .connectAsync(StringCodec.UTF8, RedisURI.create(redisUri));
        try {
          connection = future.get();
        } catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException exception) {
            LOG.info(exception.getMessage());
          closeConnectionsAsync();
          connection = null;
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return connection;
      }
    
      private void closeConnectionsAsync() {
        LOG.info("Close redis connection");
        if(connection != null && connection.isOpen()) {
          connection.closeAsync();
        }
        if(redisClient != null) {
          redisClient.shutdownAsync();
        }
      }
```

The issue was happening all time, But frequently geting this issue  like Caused by io.lettuce.core.rediscommandexecutionexception: moved 15596 XX.X.XXX.XX:6379, Any one can help to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you are doing port-forwarding to your redis cluster/instance using port **15596** but the actual redis ports like 6379 are not accessible from your application's network.
When redis's java client get the access to redis then tries to connect to actual ports like 6379.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RedisClusterClient`, instead of `RedisClient`. The unhandled MOVED response indicates that you are trying to use the non-cluster-aware client with Redis deployed in cluster mode.